# TransactionScope with several transactions inside

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, transactionscope

I try to use TransactionScope in this way:

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
  {
     DAL.delete();
     DAL.create();           
     ts.Complete();
  }
```

where I have independent DAL(Data Access Layer) module to do database operations. Each operation like delete(), create() is atomic, i.e. They are all committed by calling.

I have tried this code in order to wrap this two operation together as a transaction. And no matter whether I wrote ts.Complete();, they are all committed to database and no rollback happens.

How can I do in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try the same with ts.Rollback() ?

Comment: What DB and data access framework you are using? Does it support Transaction scopes?

Comment: if you are using `Sql Server` then please consult with the [MSDN TransactionScope Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) found here

Comment: There is no rollback function, just don't complete if things didn't go as expected.

Comment: Like I mentioned, ts.Complete() doesn't effect the result. i.e. I can not find way to make rollback. As the documentation says, if we don't provide ts.Complete() the operations will automatically rollback. The main problem is how to control transaction over small transactions.

Comment: Using connection is an option, but I don't want to ruin the in-dependency by adding connection parameter to every database operation.

Answer (score 0):

The TS is creating an ambient transaction which your DAL layer will automatically pick up on.  Your code implies you want the delete and create to be considered an atomic operation.  If you want them independent create another TS block after the first and move your create statement there.

If you want to rollback you need to leave the using block without called Complete on the scope, normally this happens because one of your DAL methods throws an exception.